# Libgdx iOS - GC Capability Mismatch

Tags: java, ios, libgdx, robovm

I've been working on a cross platform game with LibGDX, but I seem to have run into a wall when porting to iOS. I should note that the Android and Desktop builds run fine, but I have yet to try the web build. The error I get is:

```
ios-sim[3399:f07] Error loading/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/DVTFoundation: dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/DVTFoundation, 265): no suitable image found.  Did find:
[ERROR]     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/DVTFoundation: GC capability mismatch
[ERROR] Unable to dvtFoundationBundle. Error:
```

This is my first bout with iOS, so I'm not super familiar with the inner-workings, but from similar topics, I've seen solutions ranging from downgrading the iOS simulator, to enabling garbage collection. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to try either of these.

Also, a little bit of background on my setup, I'm running RoboVM 0.0.13 and libGDX 1.2.

Thank you in advance for any help that anyone can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out... It turns out it did have something to do with xCode and the iOS simulator. In the end, a simple update of xCode via the app store solved my problem.